# why I don't manage to install virtualbox on my chromebook?

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, virtualbox, chrome-os

I am trying to install virtualbox on my chromebook (linux beta) but every version of virtualbox I try to install it seems to be not supported.

It appear a message that say: this type of file is not supported or if I chose a debian version the installation fails.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Download the source and build it manually. I doubt though your cpu has the capabilities required.

Comment: ok thanks...maybe

Comment: you should **not** be using Kali Linux for this; Kali themselves explains what it's not meant for: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: @MarcusMüller ya thanks, I just wanted to install a different linux distro on my pc but in a virtual machine...

Comment: yeah, then don't use Kali.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is meant to run on full-featured Linux distros, not on Chromebooks which feature an extensively patched Linux kernel without development headers which allow to build the required Virtualbox kernel modules.

TLDR: It's impossible.

Comment: ook, which type of machine I should use for the scope....it really seems that these Chromebooks are useless...I am always more disappointed :(

Comment: What's "the scope"? Never heard of this application.

Comment: .....TLDR: my laptop sucks!

Comment: Why? You can install full-featured Linux on most Chromebooks.

Comment: plus, virtualbox also requires an out-of-tree kernel driver, whereas KVM virtualization is part of the default linux kernel – some (not many) chromeos kernels even have that enabled (You'd find a `/dev/kvm` in that case). Don't blame software things on your hardware!